# jQuery Mobile - Details page with custom objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm loading a list view full of items via getJSON.

But when I tap a list view item I want to arrive to the Details page for that item.

Now, in ASP.NET for example you would do Details.aspx?Id=1 but how will I do in jQuery Mobile? When I get the objects via my getJSON method. Do I need to store them in an array or something?

I should add that in my current getJSON response, none of the objects has an ID tied to it. But this is just a sandbox, I'm just playing around with jQuery Mobile and getting my feed from Flickr:

```
$(function() { 

     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("Laddar...");

     $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
       {
         tags: "cat",
         tagmode: "any",
         format: "json"
       },

       function(data) {

         $.each(data.items, function(i,item){

             $('#list')
             .append('<li><a><img src="images/de.png" class="ui-li-icon">' + item.author + '</a></li>')
             .listview('refresh');

             });

         $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

       });

});
```

What is the praxis in setting up "Details pages" in jQuery Mobile? Should I create the  in my code above with id=x and then in some way get a object at that index in my array (which I haven't created yet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off there are some things you can do to greatly improve the performance of your code:

```
$(function() { 

     var photos = {};

     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("Laddar...");

     $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
       {
         tags: "cat",
         tagmode: "any",
         format: "json"
       },

       function(data) {

         //store photo data for later
         photos = data;

         //setup an array (or string) to buffer the output
         var output = [];

         for (var i = 0, len = data.items.length; i < len; i++) {

             //add this index to the output array
             output.push('<li><a data-index="' + i + '" href="#"><img src="images/de.png" class="ui-li-icon">' + data.items[i].author + '</a></li>');

         }

         //here I am selecting the list element only once and only refreshing it once
         $('#list').append(output.join('')).listview('refresh');

         $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

       });

});
```

Now you can add a `click` event handler to the links in the `#list` list-view and create the necessary pseudo-pages for jQuery Mobile:

```
$('#list').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {

    //get the index of this page/link and cache some objects
    var $this   = $(this),
        index   = $this.attr('data-index'),
        $toPage = $('#details_' + index);

    //stop the browser from scrolling to the top of the page due to the hash mark (#) in the link's href attribute
    event.preventDefault();

    //check to see if the page for the link clicked already exists, if so then don't re-add it to the DOM
    if ($toPage.length === 0) {

        //no page was found so create one, we can access the photos object to insert data related to the link clicked
        $('body').append('<div data-role="page" id="details_' + index + '"><div data-role="content"><p>Some Key: ' + photos.items[index].some_key + '</p><a data-role="button" href="#home">Back Home</a></div></div>');

        //set the $toPage variable to the newly added page so jQuery Mobile can navigate to it
        $toPage = $('#details_' + index);
    }

    //change to the desired page
    $.mobile.changePage($toPage);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m4Yt8/

I'm not sure what your JSON looks like so I can't say for sure how to add data from the JSON object into the new pages, however the above template should be pretty close.

Comment: Sweet Jasper! Thank you so much! I am just wondering over the navigation. I have already created a html-page named "Details.html" and I want that page to take the tapped object in the list and present in there. In your code you create the html manually on the same page where the list view is. But how would I solve it to use a seperate html-file? Thank you so much again, really nice solution and approvement of code which I will carry with me.

Comment: @FernandoRedondo I made a demo and improved the code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/m4Yt8/. If you want to display the data in an external file then just use the `.delegate()` code above and instead of creating a pseudo-page and navigating to it, just navigate to the external page: `$.mobile.changePage('Details.aspx?id=' + $(this).attr('data-index'));`

Comment: Thanks! But do you know how to send along the object for the tapped list item to Details.html?id==' + $(this).attr('data-index'));?
When it comes to objective c and such you can specify a property that holds an object, but I guess that alternativeis ruled out when it comes to HTML?

Comment: You can't, of some reason, navigate to an external page with query strings?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html -- You can, you set the `data` property of the options object you pass to `$.mobile.changePage()`: `$.mobile.changePage('Details.aspx', { data : { id : 1, name : 'foobar' }, type : 'post' });`. Notice I set the method for the AJAX request to `post`, you can remove that and it will default to `get`.

Comment: That's a alternative, but if I've understood it correctly you can only access the data parameter from the server. For example in ASP or ASP.NET, PHP etc? Or am I wrong?